# Silence "unknown OID 17227: failed to recognize type of 'geography'. It will be treated as String."

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, pg

I'm using columns of type "geography" for some few "point within polygon" queries. They are too few and too simple to bundle a GIS gem, I handle it all on the SQL level.

However, every time Rails boots (rake tasks, console etc), the following warning is spit:

```
unknown OID 17227: failed to recognize type of 'geography'. It will be treated as String.
```

I'm fine with "geography" being treated as "String", but the warning triggers warning mails every time a cronjob executes any rake task.

Any idea how I can silence this warning?

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source of ActiveRecord, I can answer the question myself:

The warning is hardcoded and therefore can't be silenced by AR configuration. However, `RUBYOPT=-W0` gets rid of warnings altogether. This is a big chopper of course, but since I'm still getting those warnings in local development, I can live with a totally warning-less production system.

---

**Update 2021:**

After having updated the app to Rails 6.1, I got rid of this ugly hack and aliased the type properly in `config/initializers/types.rb`:

```
# (other custom types here)

# This application uses the PostGIS extension without the corresponding postgis
# adapter gem and therefore the "geography" type is unknown to ActiveRecord which
# causes a warning:
#
# unknown OID: failed to recognize type of 'geography'. It will be treated as String.
#
# The following silences this warning by explicitly aliasing "geography" to "text".
module PostgresGeographyExtension
  def load_additional_types(oids=nil)
    type_map.alias_type 'geography', 'text'
    super
  end
end
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.prepend PostgresGeographyExtension
```

Comment: Having a link that point to the hardcoded line would be nice!

Comment: It's easy to find, just clone the Rails repo and grep for the error message: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L507

Comment: My point was more about editing the answer rather than finding it. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the first question/answer that appears given that the title is the error, I would recommend following this answer to fix it: [What is the source of "unknown OID" errors in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559593/what-is-the-source-of-unknown-oid-errors-in-rails)

Comment: Adding the postgis gem only to silence a warning? No, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this postgresql statement executed in a rails console:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(
  <<-SQL.squish
    SELECT websearch_to_tsquery('simple', 'james m') AS some_named_value
  SQL
).to_a.first['some_named_value']
```

will show this error in the console when it runs:

`unknown OID 3615: failed to recognize type of 'some_named_value'. It will be treated as String.`

Casting the datatype of `tsquery` to the datatype of `text` removes the error in this case (it should only matter for the last `SELECT` that reads out in the `exec_query`). I assume you do something similar!

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(
  <<-SQL.squish
    SELECT websearch_to_tsquery('simple', 'james m')::text AS some_named_value
  SQL
).to_a.first['some_named_value']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider that warnings exist for a reason, and there are very often repercussions for ignoring them that may only become apparent with time (and be all the more difficult to diagnose when you've intentionally blinded yourself to them and put them out of your mind).

You were using the wrong adapter for your database. If you're getting that error, you need to change the value of `adapter` in your `config/database.yml` to be `postgis` + have the postgis adapter installed.

Comment: This is a very general statement which – in very general – may be true. But in this case, I don't use the Postgis adapter for a reason: It's a jackhammer which depends on rgeo. I'm doing only minimal geo calculations easily and efficiently done without adding rgeo to the mix. Casting the type to `text` is the better approach in this particular situation.

Comment: What sort of technical evaluation did you do to evaluate efficiency? You didn't even do the work to cast the type to text, you just silenced the warning and relied on rails to do that resolution for you when it can't resolve the type every time you interact with those records.

Comment: I tend not to pull a gem dependency like rgeo if I can achieve the same with just a couple of LOC. Maybe "efficiently" is not the right word, I just want to keep the number of gems low to prevent problems down the road when such dependencies might break e.g. because a gem is not maintained anymore. Felt safe enough to rely on Rails always falling back to String, but it's of course far from optimal.

Comment: By the way, I've long forgotten this Q just as I have my permanent solution committed in 2021: Explicitly aliasing the geography type to text. I've added it to the accepted answer above to discourage others from my initial hack.